# не нажимается кнопка под ImageView

Tags: java, javafx

Я создала кнопку чуть больше изображения и только на месте где нет изображения кнопка нажимается
Controller

```
        button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");
```

FXML

```
<Button fx:id="button" layoutX="167.0" layoutY="44.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="54.0" prefWidth="54.0" />
<ImageView fitHeight="46.0" fitWidth="38.0" layoutX="175.0" layoutY="52.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../image/reverse.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
```

Comment: Есть свойство, позволяющее кликать сквозь элемент. Названия не помню. Но почему просто не установить setGraphic для самой кнопки?

Comment: @Maxim я устанавливала эффект тот же самый под imageview не нажимается

Answer (score 0):

У вас согласно иерархии изображение добавляется поверх кнопки, а должно быть наоборот. Просто поменяйте их местами.

Comment: спасибо помогло